# kotlin compose MVVM update and edit actions does not reflect to ui in case i change data

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

I use MVVM in architecture, but when i update or add new item or edit exist item it doesnt reflect ui

I want to use MVVM in compose with room i spent much time to find best practice but i can t found that i can use.

When i add new item, item does not shown firstly bu when i add second time it shows all items in LazyColumn.

What is the best practice MVVM compose,

can you help please

Thank for help

**Navigation**

```
@Composable
fun NavigationView(itemViewModel:TodoItemViewModel){
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "home" ){
        composable("home"){
            TodoList(navController,viewModel = itemViewModel)
        }
        composable("edit/{itemId}", arguments = listOf(navArgument("itemId"){type= NavType.StringType})){
            EditTodoItemScreen(navController, todoViewModel = itemViewModel, currentItemUuid= it.arguments?.getString("itemId")?.toIntOrNull())
        }
        composable("add"){
            AddTodoItemScreen(navController, todoViewModel = itemViewModel)
        }
    } 
}
```

**Home.kt**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TodoList(navController: NavController, viewModel: TodoItemViewModel) {
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val todoListState = viewModel.mutTodoItems.observeAsState()

    val refecthCount = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = refecthCount) {
        viewModel.getAllItems()
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {TodoAppBar()},
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState)
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate("add")
                }
            ){
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "")
            }
        }
    ) { contentPadding ->

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(top = contentPadding.calculateTopPadding()),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp),

            ) {
            todoListState.value?.let { it ->
                items(it.size) { todoItemIndex ->
                    val item = todoListState.value!![todoItemIndex]

                    val show = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
                    val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
                        confirmValueChange = {
                            viewModel.deleteItem(item)
                            show.value = false
                            show.value
                        },
                        positionalThreshold = { 100.dp.toPx() }
                    )
                    SwipeToDismiss(
                        state = dismissState,
                        directions = setOf(
                            DismissDirection.EndToStart,
                            DismissDirection.StartToEnd,
                        ),
                        background = {
                            Row(
                                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                            ) {

                                val scale by animateFloatAsState(
                                    if (dismissState.targetValue == DismissValue.Default) 0.75f else 1f
                                )
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Default.Delete,
                                    contentDescription = "Delete Item",
                                    tint = Color.Red,
                                    modifier = Modifier.scale(scale)
                                )
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Default.Delete,
                                    contentDescription = "Delete Item",
                                    tint = Color.Red,
                                    modifier = Modifier.scale(scale)
                                )
                            }
                        },
                        dismissContent = {
                            if (show.value) {
                                TodoItemView(
                                    navController = navController,
                                    item = item,
                                    modifyItem = {
                                        viewModel.editItem(it)
                                    })
                            }
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
 

class TodoItemViewModel(application: Application):BaseViewModel(application) {

    var mutTodoItems = MutableLiveData<List<TodoItem>>(emptyList())
    var mutCurrentItem = MutableLiveData<TodoItem>()

    fun getAllItems(includeIds: List<Int> = emptyList(), excludeIds: List<Int> = emptyList()) {
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()

            val allItems = dao.getAllItems()

            val filteredItems = when {
                includeIds.isNotEmpty() -> allItems.filter { it.uuid in includeIds }
                excludeIds.isNotEmpty() -> allItems.filterNot { it.uuid in excludeIds }
                else -> allItems
            }
            mutTodoItems.value = filteredItems
        }
    }

    fun getItem(id:Int){
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()
            mutCurrentItem.value=dao.getItem(id)
        }
    }

    fun editItem(newItem:TodoItem){
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()
            dao.updateItem(newItem)
        }
    }

    fun deleteItem(item: TodoItem){
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()
            dao.deleteItem(item)
        }
    }
    fun addItem(item:TodoItem){
        launch {
            val dao = TodoDatabase(getApplication()).todoDao()
            dao.addItem(item)
        }
    }


}
```

**Edit View**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun EditTodoItemScreen(navController: NavController,todoViewModel:TodoItemViewModel, currentItemUuid:Int?) {
    val currentItem = todoViewModel.mutCurrentItem
    LaunchedEffect(Unit){
        currentItemUuid?.let { todoViewModel.getItem(it) }
    }
    if (currentItem.value == null){
        println("============OBJE BULUNAMADI ${currentItem}")
    }else{
        val (isRepeat, setIsRepeat) = remember { mutableStateOf(currentItem.value!!.hasInterval) }
        val (startDate, setStartDate) = remember { mutableStateOf(currentItem.value!!.time) }
        val (todoTitle, setTodoTitle) = remember { mutableStateOf(currentItem.value!!.title) }
        var ic =currentItem.value!!.color?: MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
        val (selectedColor, setSelectedColor) = remember { mutableStateOf(Color(ic)) }
        val (repeatInterval, setRepeatInterval) = remember { mutableStateOf<Long?>(currentItem.value!!.interval) }
        val (repeatIntervalText, setRepeatIntervalText) = remember { mutableStateOf(currentItem.value!!.intervalText) }

        val (hasColor, sethasColor) = remember { mutableStateOf(currentItem.value!!.hasColor) }
        val (showColorPicker, setShowColorPicker) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

        val colorState = rememberUseCaseState()

        val (hasTime, setHasTime) = remember { mutableStateOf(currentItem.value!!.hasTime) }
        val calendarState = rememberUseCaseState()
        val selectedDate = remember { mutableStateOf<LocalDate?>(LocalDate.now()) }

        val clockState = rememberUseCaseState()
        val (selectedClockText, setSelectedClockText) = remember { mutableStateOf(epochMillisString(startDate!!,"HH:mm"))    }

        val taskTypeState = rememberUseCaseState()
        val options = listOf(
            Option(
                IconSource(R.drawable.baseline_done_24, tint = Color.Green),
                titleText = "Tamam",
//            selected = true
            ),
            Option(
                IconSource(R.drawable.baseline_access_time_24, tint = hexToComposeColor("#FFA500")),
                titleText = "Devam",
            ),
            Option(
                IconSource(R.drawable.baseline_cancel_24,tint = Color.Red),
                titleText = "Başarısız",
            ),
            Option(
                IconSource(R.drawable.baseline_error_outline_24, tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.tertiary),
                titleText = "İptal",
            ),
        )
        val (hasTag, setHasTag) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        val (tagName, setTagName) = remember { mutableStateOf(options[0].titleText) }
        val (tagIcon, setTagIcon) = remember { mutableStateOf(IconSource(R.drawable.baseline_done_24)) }


        ColorDialog(
            state = colorState, selection = ColorSelection(
                onSelectNone = { },
                onSelectColor = {
                    setSelectedColor(Color(it))
                },
            ),
            config = ColorConfig(
                templateColors = templateColors
            )
        )


        CalendarDialog(
            state = calendarState,
            config = CalendarConfig(
                style = CalendarStyle.MONTH,
            ),
            selection = CalendarSelection.Date(
                selectedDate = selectedDate.value,
                onNegativeClick = { calendarState.hide() }
            ) { newDate ->
                selectedDate.value = newDate
                setStartDate(stringToLocalDateTime("${selectedDate.value.toString()} $selectedClockText").toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli())
            },
        )

        ClockDialog(
            state = clockState,
            selection = ClockSelection.HoursMinutes{hours, minutes ->
                val formattedHour = String.format("%02d", hours)
                val formattedMinute = String.format("%02d", minutes)
                println("Selected Hour : $formattedHour : $formattedMinute")
                setSelectedClockText( "$formattedHour:$formattedMinute")
                setStartDate(stringToLocalDateTime("${selectedDate.value.toString()} $selectedClockText").toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli())
            },
            config = ClockConfig(is24HourFormat = true)
        )

        OptionDialog(
            state = taskTypeState,
            selection = OptionSelection.Single(options) { index, option ->
                setTagName(option.titleText)
                option.icon?.let { setTagIcon(it) }

            },
            config = OptionConfig(mode = DisplayMode.GRID_VERTICAL),
        )


        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = {
                        Text("Not Düzenle")
                    },
                    navigationIcon = {
                        IconButton(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) {
                            Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, null)
                        }
                    })
            }
        ) { contentPaddind ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp, top = contentPaddind.calculateTopPadding()),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
            ) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = todoTitle,
                    onValueChange = { setTodoTitle(it) },
                    label = { Text("Todo Title") },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
                )

//        --------------------------------ADD REOMVE ICONS----------------------------------------------
                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(8.dp), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    if(!hasColor){
                        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.color),
                            contentDescription = "AddColor",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(24.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    sethasColor(true)
                                },
                            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                        )
                    }
                    if(!hasTime){
                        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_notification_add_24),
                            contentDescription = "Add Time",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(24.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    setHasTime(true)
                                },
                            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                        )
                    }
                    if(!isRepeat){
                        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_repeat_24),
                            contentDescription = "Add Repeat",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(24.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    setIsRepeat(true)
                                },
                            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                        )
                    }
                    if (!hasTag){
                        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_bookmark_add_24),
                            contentDescription = "Add Repeat",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(24.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    setHasTag(true)
                                },
                            tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                        )
                    }
                }
                if(hasColor){
                    Row(
                        modifier= Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .border(
                                0.dp,
                                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                            .clickable {
                                setShowColorPicker(!showColorPicker)
                                colorState.show()
                            }
                            .padding(start = 16.dp),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
//            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                    ) {

                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.round_square_24),
                            contentDescription = "Color",
                            modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
                            tint = selectedColor
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                        Text(
                            text = colorToHex(selectedColor),
                            color = selectedColor,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                                .weight(1f),
                        )

                        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_cancel_24),
                            contentDescription = "Cancel",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(20.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    sethasColor(false)
                                },
                            tint = Color.Red
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                    }
                }

                // Tarih Seçiciyi ekliyoruz
                if(hasTime){
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .border(
                                0.dp,
                                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                            .padding(start = 16.dp)
                            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                        Row(modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .clickable { calendarState.show() }
                            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_date_range_24),
                                contentDescription = "",
                                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(24.dp)
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                            Text(
                                text = selectedDate.value.toString(),
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 16.dp),
                            )
                        }
                        //            ---------------------------------ADD CLOCK ORNONE--------------
                        Row(modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .clickable { clockState.show() }
                            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_access_time_24),
                                contentDescription = "",
                                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                                modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp))
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                            Text(
                                text = selectedClockText,
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(vertical = 16.dp),
                            )
                        }
                        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_cancel_24),
                            contentDescription = "Cancel",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(20.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    setHasTime(false)
                                },
                            tint = Color.Red
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

                    }
                }

                if(isRepeat){
                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .border(
                                0.dp,
                                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                            .padding(start = 16.dp)
                            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                    ) {
                        Row(modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .clickable { }
                            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically){

                            Icon(
                                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_repeat_24),
                                contentDescription = "",
                                tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                                modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp)
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                            Text(text = "Tekrar")
                        }
                        Row(modifier = Modifier
                            .weight(3f)
                            .clickable { calendarState.show() }
                            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium),
                            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween){
                            val (selectedItemInterval, setSelectedItemInterval) = remember {mutableStateOf(1)}

                            TextField(
                                value = selectedItemInterval.toString(),
                                onValueChange = {
                                    val interval = it.toIntOrNull()
                                    if(interval!=null){
                                        setSelectedItemInterval(interval)
                                    }else{
                                        setSelectedItemInterval(1)
                                    }
                                },
                                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .weight(1f)
                                    .background(Color.Transparent),
                                textStyle = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center, fontSize = 16.sp)
                            )

                            val (isExpanded, setIsExpanded) = remember {
                                mutableStateOf(false)
                            }
                            val dropdownItems = listOf("Dakika" , "Saat", "Gun", "Hafta","Ay", "Yil")
                            val (selectedItemText, setSelectedItemText) = remember {mutableStateOf("Gun")}


                            Box(modifier = Modifier
                                .weight(1f)
                                .wrapContentSize(Alignment.TopStart)) {
                                Text(selectedItemText, textAlign = TextAlign.Center,modifier = Modifier
                                    .fillMaxWidth()
                                    .clickable(onClick = { setIsExpanded(true) })
                                    .padding(vertical = 16.dp, horizontal = 16.dp),
                                    fontSize = 16.sp)
                                DropdownMenu(
                                    expanded = isExpanded,
                                    onDismissRequest = { setIsExpanded(false) },
                                    modifier = Modifier
                                        .fillMaxWidth()
                                ) {
                                    dropdownItems.forEach{  s ->
                                        DropdownMenuItem(
                                            text = {
                                                Text(text = s, fontSize = 16.sp)
                                            },
                                            onClick = {
                                                setSelectedItemText(s)
                                                setIsExpanded(false)
                                            })
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_cancel_24),
                                contentDescription = "Cancel",
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .size(20.dp)
                                    .clickable {
                                        setIsRepeat(false)
                                    },
                                tint = Color.Red
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                        }

                    }
                }

                if (hasTag){
                    Row(
                        modifier= Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .border(
                                0.dp,
                                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
                                color = Color.White
                            )
                            .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                            .clickable {
                                taskTypeState.show()
                            }
                            .padding(start = 16.dp),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
//            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                    ) {

                        tagIcon.tint?.let {
                            Icon(
                                painter= painterResource(id = tagIcon.drawableRes!!),
                                contentDescription = "Etiket",
                                modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
                                tint = it
                            )
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                            Text(
                                text = tagName,
                                color = selectedColor,
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(vertical = 16.dp)
                                    .weight(1f),
                            )
                        }

                        Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.baseline_cancel_24),
                            contentDescription = "Cancel",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(20.dp)
                                .clickable {
                                    setHasTag(false)
                                },
                            tint = Color.Red
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))
                    }
                }

                val context = LocalContext.current

                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        val todoItem = TodoItem(
                            title = todoTitle,
                            hasColor = hasColor,
                            color = selectedColor.toArgb(),
                            hasTime= hasTime,
                            time = startDate,
                            hasInterval = isRepeat,
                            interval = repeatInterval,
                            intervalText = "$repeatInterval $repeatIntervalText",
                            hasTag = hasTag,
                            tag = tagName
                        )
                        todoItem.uuid = currentItem.value!!.uuid

                        if (todoTitle.isNotBlank()){
                            todoViewModel.editItem(todoItem)
                            todoViewModel.getAllItems()
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Not düzenlendi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            navController.navigate("home")
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Lütfen başlık bilgisini giriniz!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Düzenle")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using dependency injection (DI)?

Comment: No i am not using di

Comment: That might be the case then. On your `TodoItemViewModel`, you seem to be instantiating your DB on every function just to get your DAO. I suggest using a Singleton (a single instance) for your DB.

Comment: quick tip from the side: in your EditTodoItemScreen you don't have to use the double exclamation all the time (this: !!). Kotlin should smart cast currentItem.value ;)